# how to call dialog window Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5

I do this project using Laravel 5.

```
<td><a href="{{route('ethenics.show',$ethenic->id)}}" class="" data-toggle="modal"> {{ $ethenic->ethenicCode }} </a></td>
```

This is my Blade view file part of code. I want when I click this code open dialog box.

This is my div.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>           
            <h4 class="modal-title">Member Ethnicity   Details</h4>
        </div>

        <!-- text input -->
        <div class="modal-body">

            {!! Form::label('e_code', 'Ethnicity Code: '); !!}
            {!! Form::text('ethenicity_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'ethenicity_code', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Ethnicity Code here','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            {!! Form::label('e_name', 'Ethnicity Name: '); !!}
            {!! Form::text('ethenicity_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'ethenicity_name', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Ethnicity Name here' ,'disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This both code in same x.blade.php file. Very beginning I use following code to call this div and working fine.

```
 <td><a href="#myModal" class="" data-toggle="modal"> {!! 'Event Name '.$i !!} </a></td>
```

but now I am try different way with in my Controller method to call this div id, but I couldn't.

Controller class code:

```
public function show($id) {
    //

    $designation = Designation::find($id);
    return view('x.blade.php#myModal', compact('designation'));
}
```

My full x.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('slide_bar') 
    @include('layouts.master_entry_slide_bar')
@endsection

@section('content')


<section class="content-header">
    <h1>BASL  Ethnicity <small>page </small></h1>
</section>

<br/>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <col width='auto'>   
                        <col width='auto'>     
                        <col width='100'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Member Ethnicity Code</th>
                                <th>Member Name</th>
                                <th><p id='buttons'> <a href="{{ route('ethenics.create')}}" class="btn btn-success"> <strong> Add New Ethnicity &nbsp </strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a> </p></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                        
                            @foreach ($ethenics as $ethenic)
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="{{route('ethenics.show',$ethenic->id)}}" class="" data-toggle="modal"> {{ $ethenic->ethenicCode }} </a></td>
                                <td><a href="{{route('ethenics.show',$ethenic->id)}}" class="" data-toggle="modal"> {{ $ethenic->ethenicName }} </a></td>        
                                <td align='center'>
                                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['ethenics.destroy',$ethenic->id]]) !!}
                                    <a href="{{route('ethenics.edit',$ethenic->id)}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a> &nbsp &nbsp
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach



                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Member Ethnicity Code</th>
                                <th>Member Name</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


</section><!-- /.content -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;' data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style='float: right;'> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a>           
                <h4 class="modal-title">Member Ethnicity   Details</h4>
            </div>

            <!-- text input -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                {!! Form::label('e_code', 'Ethnicity Code: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('ethenicity_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'ethenicity_code', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Ethnicity Code here','disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


                {!! Form::label('e_name', 'Ethnicity Name: '); !!}
                {!! Form::text('ethenicity_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'ethenicity_name', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Ethnicity Name here' ,'disabled' => 'disabled']); !!}


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



<script>
    var name = document.getElementById("master_entry");
    document.getElementById("master_entry").className = "active";

    var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("ane_menu");
    document.getElementById("ane_menu").className = "active";

    var slide_bar_element = document.getElementById("ane_submenu3");
    document.getElementById("ane_submenu3").className = "active";
</script>



@endsection
```

Comment: Your `id` inside your div must be also <div class="moda fade" id = "{{route('ethenics.show',$ethenic->id)}}" role="dialog">`

Comment: thank you but still no answer. when i put it... give this error. **Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/umayanga/uma/tst6/masterlaw/resources/views/pages/member_pages/ethenic/ethenic_page.blade.php)**

Comment: Above your div modal use `foreach()` for that to work

Comment: @aldrin i thin this not only call DIV . this try to reload whole page. :-( this 35 line caused to error (for each loop). can you tell it ok my controller class function.? `public function show($id) {
        //
         $ethenics = Ethenic::find($id);
         return view('pages.member_pages.ethenic.ethenic_page', compact('ethenics'));
        
    }`